# Converting string to date, with no dashes

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I have a `timestamp` field that is a string, and I need it converted to a date or datetime. My timestamp values appear as follows:

`20201123T21:11:00`

I have been googling solutions for days now, with no luck. The closest I've come to an answer is converting something like `2020-11-23T21:11:00` to a date value, but obviously that won't work because my timestamp values do not contain dashes.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
select date_parse('20201123T21:11:00','%Y%m%dT%H:%i:%s')
```

For example:

```
select date_parse(timestamp_field,'%Y%m%dT%H:%i:%s') from table
```

Reference: [Date and Time Functions and Operators — Presto Documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)

Comment: Presto supports this format "natively", see [`from_iso8601_timestamp()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp).